# Enter Key Issue In ComboBox with AutoCompleteMode set to Append

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox, windows

Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> key clears text of `ComboBox` when drop down is open in a `ComboBox` with `AutoCompleteMode` set to `Append`.

We know in widows forms when the `AutocompleteMode` property in the `ComboBox` is set to `Append` then we get the values before we type the complete text of an item.

Problem is here:

- I click the dropdown button and open the drop down
- I try to enter some characters, I get the values as expected and it completes the text.
- But when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> it deletes the text of combo box.

How can I have `Append` option and also make pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> when the Dropdown is open, keep entered text and don't remove it.

---

I tried the None option in the "Auto complete Mode" property it is working fine but there is no append of data....

I dont need the suggest and suggest append options in the "Auto complete Mode" property since it opens another dropdown window....

I need to type data while the data in the dropdown box is listed and when i get the append values just by clicking enter button it should work(without getting deleted)...

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the dropdown is closed, it works as expected, but when the dropdown is open, pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> closes the dropdown and removes entered text.

As a solution you can derive from `ComboBox` and override [`IsInputKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.isinputkey(v=vs.110).aspx) this way:

```
public class MyComboBox : ComboBox
{
    protected override bool IsInputKey(Keys keyData)
    {
        switch ((keyData & (Keys.Alt | Keys.KeyCode)))
        {
            case Keys.Enter:
            case Keys.Escape:
                if (this.DroppedDown)
                {
                    this.DroppedDown = false;
                    return false;
                }
                break;
        }
        return base.IsInputKey(keyData);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution... Where do I need to include the override methiod ? Do I need to create any event when the dropdown is clicked and try the override method there ? Can you help me in understanding the solution ?

Comment: As you see in the answer, you should create a new class `MyComboBox` inherited from `ComboBox` and use it instead of `ComboBox`.

Comment: I have created this class in my form.cs file... and I have my previous code where i use the Combobox_commodity to display more than 100 records.... How can I inherit this class with the already exsisting commodity box ? I'm sorry I'm new to this winforms please guide in this one....

Comment: Put the code in a separate file in your project. Don't put it in form class. Then open your form.designer.cs and replace `System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox` with `MyComboBox`.

Comment: Also to verify the answer, I recommend using a simple form. Put the new component which is available at top of toolbox in your project components tab. Then add some items and set it's auto complete mode and auto complete source and test the solution.

Comment: Awesome bro... You are life saver.... thanks it got worked... and thanks a lot for teaching me to do it...

Answer (score 0):

In vb.NET, you must do it in event `keydown`:

```
  Private Sub ComboBox2_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles ComboBox2.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then TextBox7.Focus()
    End Sub
```